# Access socket.io from another file in node.js

Tags: node.js, next.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm creating an application in socket.io, I'm working with real-time and for that reason I need to be in constant connection with my front-end application.

I'm using third party tools that don't offer the websocket request method (Tool is Zapier.com).

The user needs to be notified when a new message appears, and for that reason I created a route for that, however to make a real-time application it is necessary that the socket is working, but inside my controller I cannot access it and it sends a . emit, follow the code below for a better explanation:

*Flowchart*
[image]

*index.js*

```
  const express = require("express");
  const connectDb = require("./config/dbConnection");
  const errorHandler = require("./middleware/errorHandler");
  const cors = require("cors");
  const Chat = require("./models/chat");
  const Board = require("./models/board");

  const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
  const app = express();
  const http = require("http").Server(app);
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(express.json());
  connectDb();

  //Routes
  app.use("/auth", require("./routes/authentication"));
  app.use("/chat", require("./routes/chat"));
  app.use("/board", require("./routes/board"));
  app.use("/time", require("./routes/functions/time"));
  app.use("/suporte", require("./routes/functions/time"));
  app.use(errorHandler);

  http.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`✅ Servidor funcionando perfeitamente na rota: ${port}`);
  });

  const io = require("socket.io")(http, {
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
    },
  });

  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("load tickets", async ({ userID }) => {
      try {
        socket.join(userID);

        const chats = await Chat.find({ user_id: userID });
        const board = await Board.find({ user_id: userID });

        if (userID !== undefined) {
          if (chats !== [] && board.length !== 0) {
            const transformedObject = {};
            const data = board.map((board) => {
              return {
                id: board._id,
                title: board.title,
                description: board.description,
                items: chats.filter((i) => i.status === board._id.toString()),
                isDropDisabled: board.isDropDisabled,
                isInitiateChat: board.isInitiateChat,
                isViewChat: board.isViewChat,
              };
            });

            data.forEach((item) => {
              transformedObject[item.id] = {
                title: item.title,
                description: item.description,
                items: item.items,
                isDropDisabled: item.isDropDisabled,
                isInitiateChat: item.isInitiateChat,
                isViewChat: item.isViewChat,
              };
            });

            socket.emit("tickets is here", transformedObject);
          } else if (chats === [] && board.length !== 0) {
            socket.emit("tickets is here", board);
          }
        } else {
          socket.emit("tickets is here", null);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });

    socket.on("update ticket", async ({ userID, id, status, newData }) => {
      try {
        const updatedChat = await Chat.findOneAndUpdate(
          { numero: id },
          {
            status: status,
          },
          {
            new: false,
          }
        );

        if (userID !== undefined) {
          socket.to(userID).emit("updated ticket", newData);
          return updatedChat;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
```

*Controller* // Emit socket in this file

```
  const createChat = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { name, picture, responsavel, numero, status, liveChat } = req.body;
  if (!picture || !responsavel || !numero || !status) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Todos os campos é obrigatório!");
  }

  const chat = await Chat.create({
    user_id: req.params.user,
    name,
    picture,
    responsavel,
    numero,
    status,
    liveChat,
  });

  res.status(201).json(chat);
});

//Ex: socket.emit("new ticket", chat)
```

*Client*

```
useEffect(() => {
socket.on("new ticket", (data) => setChats(data));
}, [socket]);
```

Comment: Pleaseeeee help me